# What is the correct syntax for a member async arrow function with an access modifier?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

For some reason this compiles but jest tests fail to recognize the function when trying to spy on it.

```js
export default class Example {
  public memberFunction = async (
    parameter1: string,
    body: MemberFunctionRequestBody,
  ): Promise<MemberFunctionResponse> =>
    await someAsyncAction();
}
```

Without the modifier it works fine

```js
export default class Example {
  memberFunction = async (
    parameter1: string,
    body: MemberFunctionRequestBody,
  ): Promise<MemberFunctionResponse> =>
    await someAsyncAction();
}
```

Alternatively the non arrow function works as well, but I'm interested in knowing why it doesn't work as an arrow function.

```js
export default class Example {
  public async memberFunction (
    parameter1: string,
    body: MemberFunctionRequestBody,
  ): Promise<MemberFunctionResponse> {
    return await someAsyncAction();
  }
}
```

The jest test that spies on this looks like

```js
beforeAll(() => {
  memberFunctionSpy = jest.spyOn(Example.prototype, 'memberFunction');
});
```

But it throws a runtime exception

> Cannot spy the memberFunction property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`